# css3 animation using html5 data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use one of the css animation framework called [Animate.css](https://daneden.me/animate/) in a way that I can effectively manage multiple animations.

I have a markup like the following for example.

```
<div data-animation="fadeInUp" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#ddd"></div>
```

And jquery as follows

```
$(function () {
    $('div').addClass('animated ' + data('animation'));
});
```

So when document is loaded the div should start executing `fadeInUp` animation from the css framework referenced.

In a real context, I would be using jquery scroll plugin to detect the x, y position to find when to fire animation but this is to just get started.

I must have got something wrong, it doesn't do anything.

Here is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/9aE2N/4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    var $divToAnimate = $("div"); // This will animate all the div elements in doc
    $divToAnimate.addClass('animated ' + $divToAnimate.data('animation'));
});
```

See for instance your Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/9aE2N/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use jQuery you can add the classes (animated fadeInUp):

```
<div id="foo" class="animated fadeInUp" data-animation="zoomInDown" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#ddd">
</div>
```